# mysql query to json convertor

Tags: mysql, sql, json, command

How can I convert below query to json?

```
SELECT id ,name ,AddTime(created_at ,'04:30:00') as created_at2
```

I mean that I need something like this:

```
"select":[ "id","name" ], 
"from":[
"table_name"
],
```

but I don't know how to use `AddTime(created_at ,'04:30:00') as created_at2`

Comment: can you please add your expected JSON output?

Comment: it sill not clear why you would need this output. I feel like you need this output to use/invoke a specific framework, library. If it possible, please also provide the associated library.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are looking for [`JSON_OBJECT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) function in order to construct a JSON value such as

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                   'id', id, 
                   'name', name, 
                   'created_at2', AddTime(created_at ,'04:30:00') 
                   ) AS js
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=95fcbdfaf3249da111347ce9b11930e2)</kbd>

**Edit** : perhaps you need to add [`JSON_ARRAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) function such as

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'select',
                    JSON_ARRAY( id, name, AddTime(created_at ,'04:30:00') )
                   ) AS js
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e0a55e51e65c412d656e0b1a53fee3b3)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need something like this: "select":[
"id","name" 
],   but I don't know how to use AddTime(created_at ,'04:30:00') as created_at2